# Determine if Recovery Code has been used in Laravel Fortify

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

Is it possible to determine whether or not a recovery code has already been used within Laravel Fortify?

Comment: I'm using the following package: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify There's a method to get the list of recovery codes but there's no keys against them like `used` to check if they have been used and used codes aren't stored anywhere either.

Comment: But Fortify do this for you. I mean, it generate new replace code once one of them has already been used...right?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box that I know of, however, you could implement something yourself.

A basic workflow might look like the following:

```
try {
    // grab the codes for the currently authenticated user
    $codes = json_decode(decrypt(auth()->user()->two_factor_recovery_codes), true);

    // if the provided code exists in the array of codes stored in the DB for the authenticated user
    if (in_array($code, $codes)) {
        // remove the associated code and reindex the array
        $codes = array_values(array_diff($codes, [$code]));

        // optionally add a new recovery code
        array_push($codes, Laravel\Fortify\RecoveryCode::generate());

        // save the recovery codes back to the database
        auth()->user()->two_factor_recovery_codes = 
            encrypt(json_encode(array_values($codes)));
        auth()->user()->save();
    }
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (EncryptException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'd like to loop through the recovery codes and display to the user the ones that have already been used. How does Fortify know if a code has been used or not?

Comment: @Polarize Fortify doesn't do that out of the box. A small adjustment to the above will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

By default whenever a recovery code is used, that individual recovery code is deleted and replaced with a new one:

**fortify/TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController** controller:

```
public function store(TwoFactorLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $request->challengedUser();

        if ($code = $request->validRecoveryCode()) {
            $user->replaceRecoveryCode($code);

            event(new RecoveryCodeReplaced($user, $code));
        }

    //...
    }
```

**fortify/src/TwoFactorAuthenticatable** trait:

```
/**
     * Replace the given recovery code with a new one in the user's stored codes.
     *
     * @param  string  $code
     * @return void
     */
    public function replaceRecoveryCode($code)
    {
        $this->forceFill([
            'two_factor_recovery_codes' => encrypt(str_replace(
                $code,
                RecoveryCode::generate(),
                decrypt($this->two_factor_recovery_codes)
            )),
        ])->save();
    }
```

Looking back this has been the behaviour since version one

There is therefore no method that does what you want, but it is safe to assume that all recovery codes available to the user have not been used before. If you did want to log recovery code use, there is an event you can listen to `RecoveryCodeReplaced` from Fortify >1.8